# Как создать базу данных с помощу libsqlite3?

Tags: c, sqlite

Во всех туториалах почему-то начинают не с создания базы данных, а с открытия её, а как собственно создать её?

```
if (!fs_exists(SQLITE_DB))
    // Что делать?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite автоматически создаёт файл базы данных при его отсутствии. Поэтому все и начинают с его открытия без проверки - при открытии отсутствующий файл всё равно будет создан движком. Но могут быть проблемы, если для создания не хватит прав или путь неверный.